# NSUserDefaults behaviour with app update

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method in my iOS app that updates the application when detects when my server has a greater version for my app (a new ipa version). If the user wants to download it, the app updates itself on the iPad.

The thing is that I want to update some entities atributes from the DB when the app opens the new version for the first time, but i'm not sure how to. I can't debug it cause when I download the latest ipa, for XCode the app crashed.

I was thinking about doing something like this in the AppDelegate.m:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
{
   //do the stuff i wanna do
}
else
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    // This is the first launch ever
}
```

But I don't know if this [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"] was set to YES before the update, cause the process should be:

1)Launch the app for the first time ever.
2)The app detects a newer version.
3)Download the same app -> At this point apple "replace" the older version to the newer one.
4)Open the newer version app.
5)Do the stuff i wanna do ONLY for the first time I launch the new version.

Comment: Why not store the version when you launched and check if the old value matches the current version?

Comment: I have to assume this is development for jailbroken iOS devices since you wont be allowed to do this on the AppStore.

Comment: @Brad.. or enterprise distribution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an integer stored in NSUserDefaults with a version number hard-coded for each version of the app.  If the integer is lower than the hard-coded version, prompt for updates:

```
NSInteger currentVersion = 3; // increment with each new version

if ([[NSUSerDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HasLaunchedForVersion"] < currentVersion) {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:currentVersion forKey:@"HasLaunchedForVersion"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    // This is the first launch for this version

} else {
    // App hasn't been updated since last launch
}
```

Comment: How does this answer your question. you said you want a code to run when old version updated. and not when installing the new version without having the old one. this code will run on both cases. while my approach does not!!

Comment: The thing is that when you install a new version, the old is replaced with the new one automatically (See the third step on the process). As you said, as the NSUserDefaults is not removed, so the old version will be stored in the HasLaunchedForVersion and the newer version will be in the currentVersion variable. Of course, the currentVersion wont be 3, but I think this answers correctly my question.

Comment: Everytime I launch the app I'll ask if the version that is stored in HasLaunchedForVersion is greater than the version I'm running, and if it is then the app will be the newer one, and launched for the first time, so then i have to set this new version to the HasLaunchedForVersion to make the app not enter to this condition for the next times.

Comment: instead currentVersion I use NSBundle CFBundleShortVersionString

Answer (score 0):

> They will not be removed. And will have old values.

if "HasLaunchedOnce" is used in the old version. use a new one and call it "HasUpdateLaunchedOnce".

Check both values and decide what do you want to do.

```
if (HasLaunchedOnce exists && HasUpdateLaunchedOnce not exists)
  // proceed
```

Comment: Ok, but I can't think of a way to set to YES the HasUpdateLaunchedOnce in true only when I launched the updated for the first time..

Comment: you mean something that you only want to do for people who updated from old to new. and not for who is downloading the new one for the first time?

Comment: Does HasLaunchedOnce exist in the old version?

Comment: Both answers are Yes.

Comment: What I understood from that condition is that I'll enter everytime I launch the app (older or newer version) except for the first time, when the HasLaunchedOnce not exists. Afer the first time, the HasLaunchedOnce exists and the HasUpdatedLaunchedOnce not. The answer from @Teddy was very clear to me, indeed. Thanks anyway! :)