# How to detect if app automatically updated in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7

I want to be able to display an alert describing what's new when an app has been updated.  What's the best way to do this, especially considering iOS 7 automatically updates apps?  Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to differentiate between an app being updated by the user and the app being updated automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the app version in NSUserDefaults. Then if the old app version != current app version you can display your dialog

Version #:

```
NSString * version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

Set:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:version forKey:@"appVersion"];
```

Get:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults objectForKey:@"appVersion"];
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful!
  But FYI: [[NSBundle mainBundle] version] does not work.  I needed to reference the app version number by: 
NSDictionary *infoDict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString *currentVersionNumber = [infoDict objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

Comment: you are correct. thank you. I edited the answer. I had written a helper to allow version to return the same. If you like the answer, accept it by hitting the checkmark on the left.

Comment: @Tanya: if this question solved your problem please mark it as correct so the topic will be closed

Comment: Do I need to do anything other than click the check mark to mark it as correct?  Sorry - I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

When the user starts your app, check a version string in user defaults or a file or database.

If you want to do it around the time the app is updated, you might be able to use push notifications in conjunction with the version check. I don't know whether you can get the new app to check the version in the background, though (never used push notifications myself).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout my question I've made some weeks ago ([NSUserDefaults behaviour with app update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732311/nsuserdefaults-behaviour-with-app-update)). I think can solve your problem.

The idea is to use NSUserDefaults to store the last version that your device have ever ran, and if a greater version than the one I've got stored in the NSUserDefault object is going to be run, then you do whatever you want to do, in this case displaying an alert describing what's new when the app has been updated.