# How to do some actions on update app version from AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Is it possible to do some actions like add/delete directories, files from app directory on updating to new version from AppStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the current bundle version:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]
```

and perform your actions if both the version is the new one and the user already has the old files installed in his documents directory. Remember to also write a flag in the user's defaults to avoid doing your update actions more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Answer Teddy provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732311/nsuserdefaults-behaviour-with-app-update) you can use NSUserDefaults to store an app version number onto the IOS device, then hardcode as a public variable the version of your app.  Then all you need to do is compare the hard coded version with the NSUserDefault already stored on the user's device and check if they do not match.  If they do not match than the app MUST have been updated (or you hardcoded the wrong value into your NSUserDefault) and you can take it from there.

EDIT: don't hardcode a public variable, andreamazz has it correct, you can check your bundle version number